# Find the equation of the line that passes through a point and is contained on a cylinder

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I need to find the vector equation of the line that passes through the point (5,0,5) and is contained on the elliptic cylinder given by $\frac{x^2}{5^2}+\frac{y^2}{4^2}=1 $

I know I only have to find the vector of the direction of the cylinder's generatrix that passes through the point, but I don't understand how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(5,0,5)$ lies on the elliptic cylinder.

$\mathbf{r}(t)=(5,0,0)+t(0,0,1)$ is a line which lies on the elliptic cylinder and passes through this point.

Comment: I understand that, but I need to get to a concrete answer in the form r(t)=(5,0,5)+t(x,y,z) with (x,y,z) the vector I need

Comment: @VictorSMtz You can choose $(x,y,z)$ to be $(0,0,1)$, or any non-zero scalar multiple of $(0,0,1)$. You need the direction vector to be parallel to the $z$-axis.